# Why do "Classifier" and "Extension" exist when adding a new component to the Nexus repository?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

Why do fields exist? Why is the "Extension" field mandatory?

[image]

Comment: Because you can upload a file like `xyz.pom` or a file `xyz.jar` or `xyz.war` or alike...and the resulting artifact could have the same extensions...